# Work out premium in a textbox from database value

Tags: vb.net

Market value.

I need to work out premium the calculation is as follows:

5% on first $100 000 then $10 for each R10 000 or part of R10 000 thereafter.

So not sure how to do this.

My idea:

get value from my dataset.

```
Dim Value1 as bool
Dim Value2 as bool
Dim premium as bool
```

`Dim price As String = Convert.ToString(dsVehicleFill.Tables[0].Rows[0]["VEH_MarketPrice"])` <-- Does not work.

Calculation:

```
Value1  = price/0.05
value2 = Value1 - price
```

I cant see how to do this. Im new to codeing so im stuck here.

Comment: When you say "does not work", what do you mean? Does it throw an exception? If so, what's the error message? Does it produce a wrong value? Do you have NULLs in that field?

Comment: you several questionable type conversions.  `value1 = price / .05` since price is a string it is like `"cat" / 2` then converting the result (a float) to a boolean.  Use `Option Strict`

Answer (score 1):

The question about working out premium is more a math problem than a programming problem, but there are several things going on here:

```
Dim Value1 as bool
Dim Value2 as bool
Dim premium as bool
```

The `bool` data type is meant to represent Boolean values, i.e. their value is expected to be either 1 or 0. It makes no sense to use them here: You'll want your variables to be of type `Double` instead, which is suitable for fractional calculations involving currency.

As for the problem of pulling a value from your DataTable, you'll need to be more specific about what isn't working.

Now, as for the Premium formula, let's break it down (you switch between $ and R (which I assume to mean South African Rand), I'm going to just use dollars in this example):

1. The first $100000 earns a 5% premium
2. The remaining amount earns a premium of $10 for every $10000, including the final portion if it's < $10000

So you can approach the calculation with an algorithm like this:

1. Compare the value to $100000
2. If the value is <= $100000

   - The premium = `value * 0.05`
3. If the value is > $100000

   - Calculate the remainder after subtracting 100000
   - Divide the remainder by 10000 to find the number of $10 premiums to apply (N.B.: In many other languages, expressing `x / 10000` will result in *integer* division, dropping any fractional component. You can force Double division by writing your constant like so: `x / 10000.0`. Fortunately, VB.NET defaults to Double division, as Plutonix points out in the comments.)
   - Take the Ceiling of this number (i.e. round it up to the nearest integer)
   - The premium = `$5000 (5% of the first $100000) + Ceiling * $10`

Implementing this in Visual Basic is left as an exercise to the reader. :)

Comment: I *think* `R` was meant to indicate remainder

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Fortunately, that's how I interpreted it in the example.

Comment: good walk through, but your NB is not quite right.  `x / 10000` results in a Double in VB - Integer division is forced with `x \ 10000`.  Doesn't hurt anything, but some nit-picker might take issue or downvote.

Comment: Thanks for the correction - I was thinking of the semantics in C# and elsewhere. I'll update my answer.